# Request administrator rights on Win Vista/7 from a c++ app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, windows-vista, uac

I found info on how to do it in c#, but how to make a C++ app pop-up that UAC "Run as administrator" when it is run?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the manifest in Visual Studio in:

Project >> Properties >> Configuration Properties >> Linker >> Manifest File >> UAC Execution Level.